# How to get cookie value in cypress from a cy.request response?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using the following before my test to try and get a cookie value from the request

```
cy.request({
            method:'GET',
            url:`https://test:test!@mf-test-magento19.test.com/meat/meat-chicken.html`
            })
            .then((response) => {
                cy.getCookie('frontend').should('exist');
            })
```

However, it only returns the value null as it is not looking at the request only whats in the browser and to which I have not set the baseurl or have a cy.visit() currently. How can I get the value of a cookie in that request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are in headers, so you need to get them there:

```javascript
cy.request({
    method:'GET',
    url:`https://test:test!@mf-test-magento19.test.com/meat/meat-chicken.html`
})
.then((response) => {
    const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
    cookies.forEach(cookie => {
        // parse cookies and do what you need with them
    });
})
```

Something more about this to read:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5469

Comment: This helped a lot thank you! Also led me to understand what parsing is when I tried to read that cookie value thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just started exploring cypress for my React application and pretty new to java script. I am stuck and unable to proceed, any suggestions please?

I have an array of cookie objects from which I want to retrieve and store the K/V pair (In my case it's -> "name: value") for the 4 arrays in the cookies.
I am totally clueless how to fetch and store this value in a variable so i can use it in next request.

[image: mycookies]

code:

cy.request({
method: 'GET',
url: `https://myaplicationurl/login`

```
}).then((response) => {


    expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
    const sessioncookies = cy.getCookies()
        .should('have.length', 4)
        .then((cookies) => {
         
            for (let key of Object.keys(cookies)) {

                var keys = key.values
                alert(key);
            }

            for (let value of Object.values(cookies)) {

                alert(value);
            }

            var valueAtIndex = cookies[0];
            const indexvalue = cy.log(valueAtIndex)


        })



})
```